# Knockout: Best way to bind visibility to both item and a parent property?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am creating an edit screen where I want people to delete items from a list. The list is displayed normally, until the "controller" object goes into edit mode. Then the user can delete items. Items should be flagged for deletion and displayed as such, then when the user saves the edit, they are deleted and the server notified.

I actually have this all working, but the only way I could do it was using literal conditions in the bindings, which looks ugly and I don't really like. Is there a better way of doing it?

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L1e7zwyv/

Markup:

```
<div id="test">
        <a data-bind="visible: IsViewMode, click: edit">Edit</a>
        <a data-bind="visible: IsEditMode, click: cancel">Cancel</a>
        <hr/>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: Items">
                <li data-bind="css: CssClass">
                        <span data-bind="visible: $parent.IsViewMode() || $data._Deleting(), text: Value"></span>
                        <!-- ko if: $parent.IsEditMode() && !$data._Deleting() -->
                                <input type="text" data-bind="value: Value"/>
                                <a data-bind="click: $parent.deleteItem">Del</a>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Code:

```
function ItemModel(val)
{
        var _this = this;

        this.Value = ko.observable(val);
        this._Deleting = ko.observable();

        this.CssClass = ko.computed(
                function()
                {
                        return _this._Deleting() ? 'deleting' : '';
                }
        );
}

function ManagerModel()
{
        var _this = this;

        this.Items = ko.observableArray([
                new ItemModel('Hell'),
                new ItemModel('Broke'),
                new ItemModel('Luce')
        ]);

        this.IsEditMode = ko.observable();
        this.IsViewMode = ko.computed(function() { return !_this.IsEditMode(); });

        this.edit = function(model, e)
        {
                this.IsEditMode(true);
        };

        this.cancel = function(model, e)
        {
                for(var i = 0; i < _this.Items().length; i++)
                        _this.Items()[i]._Deleting(false);

                this.IsEditMode(false);
        };

        this.deleteItem = function(model, e)
        {
                model._Deleting(true);
        };
}

ko.applyBindings(new ManagerModel(), document.getElementById('test'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you could:

- wrap another span around to separate the bindings but this would be less efficient.
- use both a `visible:` and `if:` binding on the same element to achieve the same functionality,
- write a function on the itemModel `isVisible()` accepting the parent as an argument making your binding `visible: $data.isVisible($parent)`.
- Afterthought: If this comes up in multiple places you could write a helper function to combine visibility bindings

  ```js
  // reprisent variables from models
  var v1 = false;
  var v2 = false;
  var v3 = false;


  // Helper functions defined in main script body - globally accessible
  function VisibilityFromAny() {
    var result = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++ ) result |= arguments[i];
    return Boolean(result);
  }

  function VisibilityFromAll() {
    var result = true;
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++ ) result &= arguments[i];
    return Boolean(result);
  }


  // represent bindings
  alert(VisibilityFromAny(v1, v2, v3));
  alert(VisibilityFromAll(v1, v2, v3));
  ```

The third option is the most popular technique with MVVM aficionados like yourself for combining variables in a single binding from what I've seen, it makes sense and keeps all the logic away from the view markup in the view models.

Personally I like the syntax you have at present, (even though I count myself amongst the MVVM aficionado gang as well) this clearly shows in the view markup that the visibility of that element is bound to 2 items rather then hiding these details in a function.

Comment: The visible and if bindings on the same element is an interesting idea, but I can't use "if" and "text" together so would require some changes, and I think you're right, anything other than what I've got obscures the display logic quite badly. I did think of the multiple condition elements using a couple of <!-- ko -->  conditions, but discarded that idea for similar reasons. This is the most useful answer so far though.

Answer (score 0):

I try to think of view models as a model for my view, not just a place where logic resides.  When possible I also try to move complex logic back the view model and use descriptive names for my variables so the code is more readable.

I would suggest adding this to your view model -

```
var isViewable = ko.computed(function () { return IsViewMode() || _Deleting(); });
var isEditable = ko.computed(function() { return IsEditMode() && !_Deleting(); });
```

And in your view -

```
<li data-bind="css: CssClass">
        <span data-bind="visible: isViewable, text: Value"></span>
        <!-- ko if: isEditable -->
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: Value"/>
                <a data-bind="click: $parent.deleteItem">Del</a>
        <!-- /ko -->
</li>
```

This cleans the bindings up and allows you to more easily adjust the logic without having to do many sanity checks in your view and view model both.  Also I personally name variables that return a boolean such as this as isWhatever to help be more descriptive.

The benefit is that as your view and view model grow larger you can keep the DOM clean of clutter and also your view model becomes **testable**.

**Here is a 'code complete' version of your fiddle with this added** -

http://jsfiddle.net/L1e7zwyv/3/

Comment: I didn't think you could reference the $parent/$data variables directly from a view model? I haven't upgraded to KO3.0 for any of my projects yet though

Comment: @Dead.Rabit yes we dont have access to those until unless we use binding handlers where we get access via `bindingcontext` as far i know .

Comment: :)  @Dead.Rabit I directly referenced the code you put in but you are correct you would need to pull out the $parent reference and simply use your variables, seems like a trivial issue.

Comment: Not sure where you are going with this, to be honest; your code in the computeds does not reference the functions using "this", so this gives a runtime error anyway, and in my code IsViewMode is on the owner object to _Deleting, so cannot be referenced in the computed anyway without refactoring to pass the owner on item creation.

Comment: @Whelkaholism Check the fiddle I just added.  You could use multiple ways of doing this such as passing a reference or using apply or call to do so inherently.  Personally I prefer legible code so I passed a reference but feel free to implement how it fits into your architecture best

Comment: Ah yes, I see now. That works quite nicely, but in the real world code it would be a bit harder to manage passing the manager item in all the time as the item object is a common one used all over the place, and there are various modes it can be in beyond the simple viewable/editable. Very clean markup on this one though. I'll leave this question for a bit to see if there are any cunning solutions to come, but will mark this as the answer if not as it best captures what I was trying to achieve in simplifying the HTML.

Comment: @Whelkaholism Sure, one thing to keep in mind is that either way (referencing $parent or passing in the manager) you would need to ensure that the context being bound to contains the observables you require.  In the View you would not be able to gracefully fail but in the view model you could use something conditional logic to properly handle the error.

Comment: @PWKad just too good mate passing parent reference to child as parameter #appreciable . i done couple of times in such way but you nailed it .cheers